# Rewrite URL , 404 File not found

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to remove 2 folders path from the URL but I cant get that to work.
My URL looks like this: `http://example.com/files/uploads/PP/test.pdf`
I would like to remove the /files/uploads from the URL so that I remain only with `http://example.com/PP/test.pdf`.

My Rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /files/uploads/
RewriteRule ^files/uploads/(.*) /$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

The URL gets rewrited in `http://example.com/PP/test.pdf` but it says that the file does not exist.
How can I do fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `.htaccess` to actually "change" the URL. You use `.htaccess` to allow the "changed" URL to work. The URL must first be changed in your internal links (in your HTML source).

(*Aside:* You can later implement an additional redirect to redirect the "old" URL to the "new" URL - for the benefit of SEO - but that is secondary and not required to get this to "work". And since this is a `.pdf` file then that may not be a concern anyway. *This is what you are trying to do with the "redirect" you have posted.*)

So, asssuming the actual file is located at `/files/uploads/PP/test.pdf` and you are linking to `/PP/test.pdf` (the new canonical URL) then you would use the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file to internally rewrite requests from `/PP/test.pdf` back to `/files/uploads/PP/test.pdf`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^PP/test\.pdf$ files/uploads/$0 [END]
```

Where `$0` is a backrefence that contains the entire match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `PP/test.pdf` in this case.

To match any `.pdf` URL that is one path-segment deep (ie. `/<path-segment>/<file>.pdf`) then modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* accordingly. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+\.pdf$ files/uploads/$0 [END]
```

Reference:

- [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)
  Specifically, [@IMSoP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254596/369434).

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite.

For the past 2 days I was trying to get that to work and couldn't understand why it wasnt working.
For my usecase is SEO not relevant but thanks for the tip.